# How to update multiple tickets OTRS 5 - Rest

Tags: rest, otrs

If the responsible team doesn't solve the problem at an specific SLA, then the ticket has to be closed and another approach to solve the problem will be executed.

One or more tickets must be closed if this scenario exists.

I know how to close one ticket at a time, but this is not optimal to the situation, because there is like 1k tickets in this scenario.

**Update Ticket**

```
{
    "UserLogin": "user",
    "Password": "password",
    "TicketNumber": "1234",
    "Ticket": {
        "State": "closed with workaround"       
    },
    "Article": {
        "ArticleType": "note-external",
        "Subject": "Closed",
        "Body": "Another approach will be executed.",
        "ContentType": "text/plain; charset=utf8"
    }
}
```

There's a way to update multiple tickets at once?
Or will I need to run a loop and call one at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have to loop and call/update it for each ticket it self.

You also could create a own operation which need to be written in Perl where you can do the loop in perl and update all 1k ticket with only one http call.